# DNS question nearlyfreespeech with heroku

Tags: dns, heroku, nearlyfreespeech

So I'm trying to use a domain I registered at Nearlyfreespeech(NFS) to use it with heroku. How do I do that? I am new to this, but the NFS help seems to be full of jargon and confusion, and heroku is posting email setting up video on the domain help page. Your human language input will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts to this, you'll need to add the custom domain addon to your Heroku application with the domain you intend the application to be available on, eg. www.myapp.com

Then (I've not used NFS) but you probably need to head towards something like Advanced DNS in your NFS control panel - you're looking for the ability to edit DNS records for your domain. You'll probably find a www. entry already exists - it would usually show the 'type' of record it is, if it's a series of numbers separated by dots then it's called an A record. If it is numbers with dots then you need to delete that entry and then add a new entry of type CNAME and set the host to www and the value to proxy.heroku.com. If it's already a CNAME type then you can just edit the value to be proxy.heroku.com

Hopefully that will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: i returned today and found out I've added the a record and it is now working...it just takes few hours to process I guess, that's what causes the frustration: lots of jargons with lots of entropy, latent feedback...I love stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: yep, DNS changes take a while to propagate once they've been added to be globally available on the new entry. Good luck.

Comment: I just hit this problem as well. Thanks to this post, I got over it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't add the "but..." part. My site is working with domain name "www.example.com", but how can I make it work with "example.com"? I've been trying to add it as an alias in NFS, but it redirects me to "example.nfshost.com" instead. (I would like it to go to "example.herokuapp.com")